# How to select resource with where condition enforcing having two relations in joined table

Tags: mysql

How to select resource with where condition enforcing having two relations in joined table.

For example lets say I have to tables `resource` and `item` where one resource can have many items and item can be assigned to many resources.

Now I need to select a resource which have two specific items ? how to do it in the simplest way possible ?

```
SELECT
      r.name,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(i.name))  AS itemNames
    FROM
        resources r
      LEFT JOIN resources_items ri ON ri.resourceId = r.id
      LEFT JOIN items i ON i.id = ri.itemId
      WHERE i.id= '1' AND i.id = '2'
GROUP BY r.id
```

Is this a good direction ?

Later on I'd like to select many resources based on many items. For example all resources that have id in given array or have an item with id 1 or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be using `IN()` and `COUNT()`

```
SELECT
  r.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(i.name))  AS itemNames
FROM
    resources r
  LEFT JOIN resources_items ri ON ri.resourceId = r.id
  LEFT JOIN items i ON i.id = ri.itemId
WHERE i.id IN(1,2)
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) = 2
```

For more element you just need to update your `IN` and the count need to be equal to the length of your given array

This approach is mysql specific which will use sum() to make the each filter is true like

```
SELECT
  r.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(i.name))  AS itemNames
FROM
    resources r
  LEFT JOIN resources_items ri ON ri.resourceId = r.id
  LEFT JOIN items i ON i.id = ri.itemId
WHERE i.id IN(1,2)
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING SUM(i.id = 1)  > 1
AND SUM(i.id = 2)  > 1
```

And repeat this `SUM(i.id = @itemInput)`  clause according to your input items so as compare to first approach this is also a complex one like your which will involve no. of conditions or no. of joins. while in first approach you just need to count your inputs and match in having clause

Comment: But will not that IN give me resources that have either one of items ? I need smth that will return all resources that have skill 1 and 2 or skill 2 or 3

Comment: that is why `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) = 2` is used to ensure all the items must exist

Comment: Ok true, what about more complicated example ? As the one in a comment above ?

Comment: In your version you need to add the joins as to the no. of items which will make a big query and also impact on performance i will add another version which will use same query but different no. of conditions